# Stormpath TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticateApiRequest' of undefined

Tags: node.js, stormpath

I get this error at random times when I make REST calls from my android device to my nodejs service, which is using stormpath. This type error is only thrown on the first try, if I resend the same rest request, then the error is not thrown.

What is the reason for this and how do I resolve it?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticateApiRequest' of undefined

  - get-user.js:186 Object.module.exports [as getUser]
    [webservices]/[express-stormpath]/lib/helpers/get-user.js:186:16

  - stormpath.js:80 
    [webservices]/[express-stormpath]/lib/stormpath.js:80:17

  - async.js:689 
    [webservices]/[async]/lib/async.js:689:13

  - async.js:265 iterate
    [webservices]/[async]/lib/async.js:265:13

  - async.js:284 async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries
    [webservices]/[async]/lib/async.js:284:9

  - async.js:688 _parallel
    [webservices]/[async]/lib/async.js:688:9

  - async.js:710 Object.async.series
    [webservices]/[async]/lib/async.js:710:9

  - stormpath.js:78 stormpathMiddleware
    [webservices]/[express-stormpath]/lib/stormpath.js:78:11

  - layer.js:95 Layer.handle [as handle_request]
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/layer.js:95:5

  - index.js:312 trim_prefix
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:312:13

  - index.js:280 
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:280:7

  - index.js:330 Function.process_params
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:330:12

  - index.js:271 Immediate.next
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:271:10

  - index.js:618 Immediate.<anonymous>
    [webservices]/[express]/lib/router/index.js:618:15

  - timers.js:420 Immediate.immediate._onImmediate
    timers.js:420:18

  - timers.js:368 processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
    timers.js:368:17
```

Updated:
Here is the snippet code for my server.js

```
    var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
    app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    client: {
    apiKey: {
    id:'<my_id>',
    secret:'<my_secret_key>'
    }
 },
 application: {
   href: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/<my_app_key>',
 }
 }));
// expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you share your server-side Node.js code? It seems like your application was never loaded.

Comment: I added my code snippet on how I am setting up stormpath

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest express-stormpath release on npm and see if the problem is still happening?

Comment: Thanks. Will update and see if I still have these issues.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: stack=[  Error: API key ID and secret is required.,   ,   - ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:15 newError,     [webservices]/[express-stormpath]/[stormpath]/[stormpath-config]/lib/strategy

Comment: Please update your `stormpath.init()` call, and move the `apiKey` option up a level, and remove the `client` option.  Also ensure that you don't have the `stormpath` module installed, you should only need the `express-stormpath`  module